# Gnu make: Generate a list of all subdirectories

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu

I am new to C/C++ and to gnu makefiles especially. Momentarily I have a makefile that automatically generates a list of all sources and headers in one directory in order to `make` the output binary.

as my project grows I surely do not want to lump all source and header files into one directory. but instead create (nested) subdirectories.......

Is there a way - I guess taking as starting point `subdirs := $(wildcard */)` - and further involving `for... in... ($subdirs)` to first only generate a list of the source and header files in the subdirectories and nested subdirectories ? Maybe later with addition of a `make` call for the sources and headers of every subdirectory ?

Thank you very much.

Yours sincerly
von Spotz

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$(shell)` and script it:

```
ALL_SOURCES := $(shell find * -name '*.cpp' -print)
```

(assuming you use `.cpp` as a C++ source file extension). You should have full and complete documentation of `make` already installed:

```
info -f make
```